# What is the legality of the following series?

Tags: puzzle

What is the legality of the following series?
1,11,21,1211,111221,312211,132221,11133211,31231221,13111213112211,111331121113212221...

Comment: what do you mean by 'legal'?

Comment: i mean what is the rule...

Comment: It's the "talky" (my own personal name for it) series (pronounce it loudly): one, one-one, two-ones, (one-two, two ones), (one-one, one-two, two-ones), ...

Comment: A really silly sequence. [See this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence)

Comment: wow, i get it. thanks!

Comment: Simple bonus question: Why are all digits $\le 3$?

Comment: can you prove it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you prove it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each terms enumerates the number of each present natural number in the previous one:

1

11 is one 1

21 is two 1

1211 is one 2 one 1 and so on